# How to implement offline Android Mapbox map that supports Navigation?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am implementing application for Android devices and having the problem to implement offline map that works well with showing routes and navigation to the place. I was trying to implement the solution from this link: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/offline-service/#offline-maps-and-offline-routing But this part of documentation is not clear for me :(

So far I have downloaded map in this way: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/offline/#metadata
This works fine but routes cannot be generated. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but the documentations states: `Offline packs may include map data, navigation data, or both. You specify which kind of data to include when creating a region using the region configuration object. Offline map data includes all map tiles for the specified region. Offline navigation data will allow you to generate routes that fall within the bounds of the specified region.` Did you set the data type correctly?

Comment: I think that the map I have downloaded includes only map data and not navigation data. The poin is that I am not quite sure how to properly configure offline pack that icludes both map and navigation data

Comment: Here is the documentations for creating requests: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/private-beta/offline-data/#create-a-region
Have a look at the `configuration` parameter. More details on it can be found here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/api/private-beta/offline-data/#region-configuration
Did you look at the example request? It seems to include the navigation parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offline Routing is currently re-built by Mapbox. That leaves developers the option to do offline navigation only by using the pre-1.0 Navigation SDK versions.

**To your question:**

Yes, there is a difference in offline map tiles and offline routing tiles. You need to download the offline routing tiles, so that the `offlineManager` can generate a route when offline.

You can check out my implementation of offline navigation here:
https://github.com/moritzzzzz/offline_navigation

This will only work in the test region of the Faroe islands, as no enterprise API token is required for that. If you would like to do offline navigation worldwide, you would have to talk to Mapbox sales to get such an enterprise token.

Given such a token, the implementation will work worldwide.

Comment: I cannot test it on Faroe Islands either as Iam getting Toast message saying that Offline Router not configured but Thank you anyway - that is explanation I was looking for :)